# Is there any documentation about spyder reports?

Tags: python, spyder

I just found out about spyder-reports which can both generate the python code and the HTML output from the .mdw file. I installed it with pip, but then I didn't found any way to work with it. I am using spyder 4.1.3 with python 3.6.4, and nothing changed in the interface, opening a .mdw file doesn't seem to propose anything.. How does this plugin work?

Is there any documentation, examples, I could use to figure out how it works?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. According to their GitHub issues:

> Sorry, this plugin is unmaintained now and it's not compatible with the latest release of Pweave. We'll come back to it after we release Spyder 4.

and

> This plugin is unmaintained and not compatible with the latest release of Pweave.  To help update it or see the status of that work, visit [this link](https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-reports/issues/76).

Your best bet at this time is to uninstall since the installation downgrades some packages:

```
pip uninstall spyder-reports
```

or

```
conda uninstall spyder-reports
```

Sources:

- https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-reports/issues/76
- https://github.com/nathancarter/spyder-reports/commit/5fcddd1503e17b5db8df6f0dbe7444f1698824a6